# Is there a double-meaning to "picking my belly button" in this context?

Tags: meaning, jokes

I understand all the individual words in the following remark, but there doesn't seem to be any connection between the first half and the second. I am left wondering whether there is an English idiom that gives a double-meaning to part of it (perhaps "picking my belly button"?), but if so it does not appear to be in any dictionary.

> I'm not Catholic, but I gave up picking my belly button for lint.

Reference: *[The best God joke ever - and it's mine!](http://www.guardian.co.uk/stage/2005/sep/29/comedy.religion)*

Comment: Why the downvotes and why was it closed? It was a perfectly valid language question! See psmears answer for the explanation of the pun.

Comment: The question seems to have been *completely* answered by psmears response. Anything else would be superfluous.

Comment: "So I'm at the Wailing Wall, standing there like a moron, with my harpoon."

Comment: @pavium: So all questions that have been answered get closed around here???

Comment: @vonjd, I don't know: I'm new here.

Comment: I disagree with the closing, but then I'm just a mere sub-1000 user, so I can't vote to reopen (and TPTB have decreed that jokes are (mostly) off-topic anyway)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Catholicism (and indeed many other branches of Christianity), the six weeks leading up to Easter are a time of contemplation and purification before the major festival. This period is known as *[Lent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lent)*, and it is common to deny oneself something (say, sweets, chocolate, or playing computer games) as part of one's preparations (or at least it used to be — these days there is a strong trend towards doing something *positive* such as doing something for charity).

Thus in Catholic households, at a certain time of year, it's not uncommon to hear declarations such as "I'm giving up [chocolates] for Lent".

The joke puns on the similarity in sound between *Lent* and *[lint](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lint?show=0&t=1310285511)*, a word that can be used among other things to describe the fuzzy accumulation of clothes fibres that sometimes builds up in one's navel: he's saying he's giving up *picking the lint out of his bellybutton*, but in such a way that it sounds like he's *giving up picking his bellybutton for Lent*.

For this he deserves an almighty *thwack*.

Comment: +1, Makes things clearer; I did not understand that joke either.

Comment: If "Lent" had been called "Fluff", then the joke would have been clearer.

Comment: I did not understand it either, and I'm Catholic.

Comment: What if someone is not Catholic, like myself.  Being a non-Catholic, I would say picking my belly-button is akin to picking my nose, or twiddling my thumbs, or tapping my foot -- anything that is done semi-consciously while "killing time" waiting on someone else.

Comment: @Rachel: Right, but in this context that actually doesn't matter - there's no special double-meaning in the *picking* part; the joke is a weak pun on *lint* / *lent*; this explains how the first and second halves of the comment relate. (For the record, picking one's belly-button has no special significance to Catholics.)

Comment: I figured it didn't - I was just looking for a more religiously benign justification.  If picking of the belly button (why is it even called a button is another fun question) made someone a Catholic, well we would all be Catholics dare I say!

Comment: @Neil: no, the joke would have been impossible to make (actually, it's just a pun :D)

Comment: It's a poor pun in American English, but with certain kinds of accents -- Irish or Australian -- it might work.